# css in the menu does not work because the id is pushed into the wrong container

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

i want to use this code in wordpress. The first code shows the working code. The second code shows how it is displayed in Wordpress when I use this position `<?php wp_nav_menu (array ('menu_id' => 'main-nav',)); ?>` it is packed in the ul but it has to be represented as above around the code in the surrounding container.

1. Code

```js
/* jquery.dropotron.js v1.4.3 | (c) @ajlkn | github.com/ajlkn/jquery.dropotron | MIT licensed */

(function($) {

    // Disables selection.
        $.fn.disableSelection_dropotron = function() { return $(this).css('user-select', 'none').css('-khtml-user-select', 'none').css('-moz-user-select', 'none').css('-o-user-select', 'none').css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); }

    // Dropotron prototype method.
        $.fn.dropotron = function(options) {

            if (this.length == 0)
                return $(this);

            if (this.length > 1)
                for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++)
                    $(this[i]).dropotron(options);

            return $.dropotron($.extend({ selectorParent: $(this) }, options));

        }

    // Dropotron method.
        $.dropotron = function(options) {

            // Settings.
                var settings = $.extend({

                    // Parent jQuery object.
                        selectorParent: null,

                    // Base Z-Index.
                        baseZIndex: 1000,

                    // Menu class (assigned to every <ul>).
                        menuClass: 'dropotron',

                    // Expansion mode ("hover" or "click").
                        expandMode: 'hover',

                    // Hover delay (in ms).
                        hoverDelay: 150,

                    // Hide delay (in ms; 0 disables).
                        hideDelay: 250,

                    // Opener class.
                        openerClass: 'opener',

                    // Active opener class.
                        openerActiveClass: 'active',

                    // Submenu class prefix.
                        submenuClassPrefix: 'level-',

                    // Menu mode ("instant", "fade", "slide", "zoom").
                        mode: 'fade',

                    // Menu speed ("fast", "slow", or ms).
                        speed: 'fast',

                    // Easing mode ("swing", "linear").
                        easing: 'swing',

                    // Alignment ("left", "center", "right").
                        alignment: 'left',

                    // Submenu offset X.
                        offsetX: 0,

                    // Submenu offset Y.
                        offsetY: 0,

                    // Global offset Y.
                        globalOffsetY: 0,

                    // IE Offset X.
                        IEOffsetX: 0,

                    // IE Offset Y.
                        IEOffsetY: 0,

                    // If true and mode = "fade", prevents top-level opener fade.
                        noOpenerFade: true,

                    // Detach second level menus (prevents parent style bleed).
                        detach: true,

                    // If true and detach = true, leave original menu intact.
                        cloneOnDetach: true

                }, options);

            // Vars.
                var $top = settings.selectorParent,
                    $menus = $top.find('ul'),
                    $body = $('body'),
                    $bodyhtml = $('body,html'),
                    $window = $(window);

                var isLocked = false,
                    hoverTimeoutId = null,
                    hideTimeoutId = null;

            // Main.

                // Top.
                    $top
                        .on('doCollapseAll', function() {
                            $menus.trigger('doCollapse');
                        });

                // Top level menus.
                    $menus.each(function() {

                        var $menu = $(this), $opener = $menu.parent();

                        // If a hideDelay is set, set up the event.
                            if (settings.hideDelay > 0)
                                $menu.add($opener)
                                    .on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                                        window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);
                                        hideTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                            $menu.trigger('doCollapse');
                                        }, settings.hideDelay);
                                    });

                        // Menu.
                            $menu
                                .disableSelection_dropotron()
                                .hide()
                                .addClass(settings.menuClass)
                                .css('position', 'absolute')
                                .on('mouseenter', function(e) {
                                    window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);
                                })
                                .on('doExpand', function() {

                                    // Already visible? Bail out.
                                        if ($menu.is(':visible'))
                                            return false;

                                    // Reset our "hide" timeout.
                                        window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);

                                    // Collapse everything but this menu.
                                        $menus.each(function() {

                                            var $this = $(this);

                                            if (!$.contains($this.get(0), $opener.get(0)))
                                                $this.trigger('doCollapse');

                                        });

                                    // Vars.
                                        var oo = $opener.offset(),
                                            op = $opener.position(),
                                            opp = $opener.parent().position(),
                                            ow = $opener.outerWidth(),
                                            mw = $menu.outerWidth(),
                                            isTL = ($menu.css('z-index') == settings.baseZIndex);

                                        var x, c, left, top;

                                    // If this is a top level menu ...
                                        if (isTL) {

                                            // If detach is enabled, use .position()
                                                if (!settings.detach)
                                                    x = op;
                                            // Otherwise, use .offset()
                                                else
                                                    x = oo;

                                            top = x.top + $opener.outerHeight() + settings.globalOffsetY;
                                            c = settings.alignment;

                                            // Remove alignment classes.
                                                $menu
                                                    .removeClass('left')
                                                    .removeClass('right')
                                                    .removeClass('center');

                                            // Figure out alignment and position.
                                                switch (settings.alignment) {

                                                    case 'right':
                                                        left = x.left - mw + ow;

                                                        if (left < 0) {

                                                            left = x.left;
                                                            c = 'left';

                                                        }

                                                        break;

                                                    case 'center':
                                                        left = x.left - Math.floor((mw - ow) / 2);

                                                        if (left < 0) {

                                                            left = x.left;
                                                            c = 'left';

                                                        }
                                                        else if (left + mw > $window.width()) {

                                                            left = x.left - mw + ow;
                                                            c = 'right';

                                                        }

                                                        break;

                                                    case 'left':
                                                    default:
                                                        left = x.left;

                                                        if (left + mw > $window.width()) {

                                                            left = x.left - mw + ow;
                                                            c = 'right';

                                                        }

                                                        break;

                                                }

                                            // Add alignment class.
                                                $menu.addClass(c);

                                        }

                                    // Otherwise, we're dealing with a submenu.
                                        else {

                                            // If the opener position isn't static ...
                                                if ($opener.css('position') == 'relative'
                                                ||  $opener.css('position') == 'absolute') {

                                                    top = settings.offsetY;
                                                    left = (-1 * op.left);

                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    top = op.top + settings.offsetY;
                                                    left = 0;

                                                }

                                            // Figure out position (based on alignment).
                                                switch (settings.alignment) {

                                                    case 'right':
                                                        left += (-1 * $opener.parent().outerWidth()) + settings.offsetX;

                                                        break;

                                                    case 'center':
                                                    case 'left':
                                                    default:
                                                        left += $opener.parent().outerWidth() + settings.offsetX;

                                                        break;

                                                }

                                        }

                                    // Legacy IE? Apply IE-specific offsets.
                                        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./) && RegExp.$1 < 8) {

                                            left += settings.IEOffsetX;
                                            top += settings.IEOffsetY;

                                        }

                                    // Position and show the menu.
                                        $menu
                                            .css('left', left + 'px')
                                            .css('top', top + 'px')
                                            .css('opacity', '0.01')
                                            .show();

                                    // Kludge!
                                        var tmp = false;

                                        // Non-static position fix.
                                            if ($opener.css('position') == 'relative'
                                            ||  $opener.css('position') == 'absolute')
                                                left = (-1 * op.left);
                                            else
                                                left = 0;

                                        if ($menu.offset().left < 0) {

                                            left += $opener.parent().outerWidth() - settings.offsetX;
                                            tmp = true;

                                        }
                                        else if ($menu.offset().left + mw > $window.width()) {

                                            left += (-1 * $opener.parent().outerWidth()) - settings.offsetX;
                                            tmp = true;

                                        }

                                        if (tmp)
                                            $menu
                                                .css('left', left + 'px');

                                        $menu
                                            .hide()
                                            .css('opacity', '1');

                                    // Figure out animation mode.
                                        switch (settings.mode) {

                                            case 'zoom':

                                                isLocked = true;

                                                $opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                                $menu.animate({
                                                    width: 'toggle',
                                                    height: 'toggle'
                                                }, settings.speed, settings.easing, function() {
                                                    isLocked = false;
                                                });

                                                break;

                                            case 'slide':

                                                isLocked = true;

                                                $opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                                $menu.animate({ height: 'toggle' }, settings.speed, settings.easing, function() {
                                                    isLocked = false;
                                                });

                                                break;

                                            case 'fade':

                                                isLocked = true;

                                                if (isTL && !settings.noOpenerFade) {

                                                    var tmp;

                                                    if (settings.speed == 'slow')
                                                        tmp = 80;
                                                    else if (settings.speed == 'fast')
                                                        tmp = 40;
                                                    else
                                                        tmp = Math.floor(settings.speed / 2);

                                                    $opener.fadeTo(tmp, 0.01, function() {
                                                        $opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                                        $opener.fadeTo(settings.speed, 1);
                                                        $menu.fadeIn(settings.speed, function() {
                                                            isLocked = false;
                                                        });
                                                    });

                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    $opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                                    $opener.fadeTo(settings.speed, 1);
                                                    $menu.fadeIn(settings.speed, function() {
                                                        isLocked = false;
                                                    });

                                                }

                                                break;

                                            case 'instant':
                                            default:

                                                $opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                                $menu.show();

                                                break;

                                        }

                                    return false;
                                })
                                .on('doCollapse', function() {

                                    // Not visible? Bail out.
                                        if (!$menu.is(':visible'))
                                            return false;

                                    // Collapse the menu.
                                        $menu.hide();
                                        $opener.removeClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                        $menu.find('.' + settings.openerActiveClass).removeClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                        $menu.find('ul').hide();

                                    return false;

                                })
                                .on('doToggle', function(e) {

                                    if ($menu.is(':visible'))
                                        $menu.trigger('doCollapse');
                                    else
                                        $menu.trigger('doExpand');

                                    return false;

                                });

                        // Menu's opener.
                            $opener
                                .disableSelection_dropotron()
                                .addClass('opener')
                                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                                .on('click touchend', function(e) {

                                    // Locked? Bail.
                                        if (isLocked)
                                            return;

                                    // Toggle menu.
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                        $menu.trigger('doToggle');

                                });

                        // If expandMode is "hover", set up the event.
                            if (settings.expandMode == 'hover')
                                $opener.hover(function(e) {

                                    if (isLocked)
                                        return;

                                    hoverTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                        $menu.trigger('doExpand');
                                    }, settings.hoverDelay);

                                },
                                function (e) {

                                    window.clearTimeout(hoverTimeoutId);

                                });

                    });

                // All links.
                    $menus.find('a')
                        .css('display', 'block')
                        .on('click touchend', function(e) {

                            // Locked? Bail.
                                if (isLocked)
                                    return;

                            // No href? Prevent default.
                                if ($(this).attr('href').length < 1)
                                    e.preventDefault();

                        });

                // All list items.
                    $top.find('li')
                        .css('white-space', 'nowrap')
                        .each(function() {

                            var $this = $(this), $a = $this.children('a'), $ul = $this.children('ul'),
                                href = $a.attr('href');

                            // If href is blank ("") or a hash (#), prevent the link from doing anything.
                                $a.on('click touchend', function(e) {

                                    if (href.length == 0
                                    ||  href == '#')
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                    else
                                        e.stopPropagation();

                                });

                            // If there is a link but no unordered list ...
                                if ($a.length > 0 && $ul.length == 0)
                                    $this.on('click touchend', function(e) {

                                        if (isLocked)
                                            return;

                                        $top.trigger('doCollapseAll');

                                        e.stopPropagation();

                                    });

                        });

                // Top level list items.
                    $top.children('li').each(function() {

                        var $opener = $(this), $menu = $opener.children('ul'),
                            c;

                        if ($menu.length > 0) {

                            // If we're using detach ...
                                if (settings.detach) {

                                    // If we're cloning on detach ...
                                        if (settings.cloneOnDetach) {

                                            // Make a copy of the menu.
                                                c = $menu.clone();

                                            // Leave it behind
                                                c
                                                    .attr('class', '')
                                                    .hide()
                                                    .appendTo($menu.parent());

                                        }

                                    // Detach the menu and move it to the end of the <body> element.
                                        $menu
                                            .detach()
                                            .appendTo($body);

                                }

                            // Step through menus, assigning z-indexes and submenu class prefixes as necessary.
                                for(var z = settings.baseZIndex, i = 1, y = $menu; y.length > 0; i++) {

                                    y.css('z-index', z++);

                                    if (settings.submenuClassPrefix)
                                        y.addClass(settings.submenuClassPrefix + (z - 1 - settings.baseZIndex));

                                    y = y.find('> li > ul');

                                }

                        }

                    });

                // Window.
                    $window
                        .on('scroll', function() {
                            $top.trigger('doCollapseAll');
                        })
                        .on('keypress', function(e) {

                            // Collapse all menus if the user hits escape.
                                if (!isLocked && e.keyCode == 27) {

                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $top.trigger('doCollapseAll');

                                }

                        });

                // Body.
                    $bodyhtml
                        .on('click touchend', function() {

                            if (!isLocked)
                                $top.trigger('doCollapseAll');

                        });

        };

})(jQuery);

var foo = $('#main-nav > ul');
foo.dropotron();
```

```css
#main-nav ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#main-nav ul li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 1em 0 1em; padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.35em 0.75em; border-radius: 0.5em; }
#main-nav ul li.active { background: #999; }
#main-nav ul li.active a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
.dropotron { background: #444; border-radius: 0.5em; list-style: none; margin: 0; min-width: 10em; padding: 0.75em 1em 0.75em 1em; }
.dropotron > li { border-top: solid 1px #555; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.dropotron > li:first-child { border-top: 0; }
.dropotron > li > a { color: #ccc; display: block; padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0; text-decoration: none; }
.dropotron > li.active > a, .dropotron > li:hover > a { color: #fff; }
.dropotron.level-0 { margin-top: 1.25em; }
.dropotron.level-0:before { content: ''; position: absolute; border-bottom: solid 0.5em #444; border-left: solid 0.5em transparent; border-right: solid 0.5em transparent; top: -0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="nav">
  <div id="main-nav">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-511"><a href="http://localhost/test/">Test</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513"><a href="http://localhost/test/">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512"><a href="http://localhost/test/">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

2. Code

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-511"><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

this is the code that is output when the php code is placed in the desired position. Wrong: `<div class = "menu-top-menu-container"><ul id = "main-nav" class = "menu">` Correct: `<div id = "main-nav" class = "menu-top-menu-container"><ul class = "menu">` This is what the code should look like . the code would work in the surrounding container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace  `menu_id` to `container_id`.
2. Change `menu_id` value `menu-top-menu`.
3. Finale code `<?php wp_nav_menu( [ 'container_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_id' => 'menu-top-menu'] ); ?>`

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/